# Proving/Disproving a fact about open set of $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

> Let $S\subset\mathbb{R}$ be an open set and $x\in S$. Let $T \subset S$ be the
>   largest open interval containing $x$, then $S\setminus T$ is an open
>   set.

---

My attempt:

Let $y\in S\setminus T$. Then $y \in S$ and $y \not\in T$. Since $y \in S$ and $S$ is an open set, there exists a neighborhood $I \subset S$ of $y$. We will now show that every element $z \in I$ is not in the set $T$. Otherwise if there were some element $z$ in $I$ such that $z$ is in $T$, then $T\cup I$ is a neighborhood of $z$ and so for $x$. But $T$ was the largest open interval containing $x$ (a contradiction!); thus we have that every element $z \in I$ is not in the set $T$. Thus, $I \subset S\setminus T$ and we conclude that $S\setminus T$ is an open set.

---

Is this proof okay or are there any counterexamples to this proposition?

Comment: Looks OK to me.

Comment: "The largest open interval containing $x$"? Are you sure? In that case $T=\mathbb{R}$ and $S\setminus T = \emptyset$, which is in fact an open set.

Comment: @PierreCarre I've added $T \subset S$ is this okay now?

Comment: @PierreCarre OP is taking about largest open interval containing $x$ not the largest open interval symmetric about $x$ contained in $S$. In your example $T=S$.

Comment: @PierreCarre I meant the largest interval which would be $(0,3)$ in fact.

Comment: You are correct, off course, i'll delete the comment.

Comment: The result is true. An open set in $\mathbb{R}$ is a (possibly) countable union of disjoint open intervals, so  $S = S_1, S_2, \cdots, S_n, \cdots$, with all $S_n$ open and $T = S_j$. That way $S\setminus T= \bigcup_{n \ne j} S_n$, which is still open. The proof you presented also seems fine to me.

Comment: @PierreCarre I was actually trying to prove the theorem that you mentioned by using the proposition that I've posted. I wonder if doing induction several times using this proposition would lead to correct proof or not.

Comment: I don't see how exactly induction would work, but you have already a few ingredients for the proof: For every $x \in S$ you can construct an open set $T_x = ]a_x,b_x[$; you have that $\cup_{x \in S} T_x = S$; you must check that: i. the open sets in that family are mutually disjoint ii. If that family is not finite it must be countable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the open intervals form a basis for the topology, an open set $S$ in $\Bbb R$ is a union of disjoint open intervals (finite intersections of open intervals are also open intervals).  So which ever one $x$ is contained in,  will be $T$.  Then $S\setminus T$ will be the union of the remaining intervals,  hence open.

So this exercise is really about what the open sets in $\Bbb R$ "look like".

Your way looks ok.

Comment: This wasn't an exercise in my textbook. I stumbled upon this while actually trying to prove that every nonempty subset of R is a countable union of disjoint open intervals (I am yet to prove it!). I was thinking on using this proposition and induction to prove that an open set in R is a countable union of disjoint open intervals.

Comment: I was using exercise loosely. Good luck with this.  Note that the rationals are dense in the reals, so every interval will contain a rational.

Answer (score 0):

One should first ensure that such a largest interval exists. Let $A=\{s\in S:[x,s)\subseteq S\}$. The set is not empty, because there is at least an interval containing $x$ and contained in $S$. Let $q=\sup A$ (might be $\infty$). Suppose $[x,q)\not\subseteq S$. Then there is $y\in[x,q)$, $x\notin S$; since $y<q$, there is $z\in S$ with $z\in A$. Contradiction.

By definition of supremum, no interval of the form $[x,z)$, with $z>q$, can be contained in $S$.

Similarly, if $B=\{s\in S:(s,x]\subseteq S\}$, then $(p,x]\subseteq S$, where $p=\inf B$ (might be $-\infty$).

Now, let $z\in T=S\setminus(p,q)$. Take an interval $(a,b)$ such that $z\in(a,b)\subseteq S$.

If $(a,b)\cap(p,q)\ne\emptyset$, we have that $(a,b)\cup(p,q)$ is an interval containing $x$ and contained in $S$; therefore $(a,b)\subseteq(p,q)$: a contradiction to $z\notin(p,q)$.